# Bash parsing ls lessons learned using printf and nul delimiter

Tags: bash

I have read about [the downfalls of parsing ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), printf, echo and others due to the lack of a delimiting null character.

[I asked a question about using functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550336/using-paths-from-a-function-that-uses-globbing/550338) to get around this issue, and the answer seemed to correctly state that the same issue would occur since I was using basic echo.

However, I recently read that [it is possible to output a null delimited character using printf](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) (and I would assume echo -e).

> Of course, a for loop offers the ultimate flexibility, but printf and
>   its implicit looping over arguments can cover many of the simpler
>   cases. It can even produce NUL-delimited streams, perfect for later
>   retrieval:

```
$ printf "%s\0" "${myarray[@]}" > myfile
```

If this indeed works, is it limited to certain versions of printf or bash for example, and could I rewrite my [original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550336/using-paths-from-a-function-that-uses-globbing/550338)s function to use

```
printf "%s\0" "$i"
```

instead of

```
echo "$i"
```

or can I use the following?

```
echo -e "$i\0"
```

Comment: Think about what happens when `i='\n'`

Comment: `printf '%s\0' "$i"` is fine, and in fact preferable to `echo -e`, as it is portable across POSIX-compliant shells, whereas `echo -e` is a bash extension to restore POSIX-specified behavior to `echo` in the first place.

Comment: KamilCuk has a point here. When `i='\n'`, echo will print a line feed, but printf will print `\n`. Btw, it's wiser to make use of arrays while filtering some files within a loop like `for f in glob`

Comment: Does one of you want to turn these useful-but-ephemeral comments into a useful and permanent answer? Or find a dup...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work in any Posix-compatible shell:

```
printf "%s\0" "$i"
```

Don't use `echo -e`. First, it is non-standard and on many systems it will not work at, or worse will work sporadically. And second, it will modify any backslash found in `$i`, while the whole point was to pass `$i` through untouched.